# PHP function display

Tags: php

Hello I have a four computers that I would like to ping before using.  The pinging is done via a PHP page with the following function.

```
if (isset($_POST['playgroundcheck'])) {

    function ping($PGIP) {
        require_once "Net/Ping.php";
        $ping = Net_Ping::factory();
        if (PEAR::isError($ping))
            echo $ping -> getMessage();
        else {
            /* Number of packets to send */
            $ping -> setArgs(array('count' => 2));
            $pgData = $ping -> ping($PGIP);
            //    print_r($pgData);

            if ($pgData -> _received > 0) {
                return true;
                //echo "<h1><font color=\"green\">ON</font></h1>";
            } else {
                //echo "<h1><font color=\"red\">OFF</font></h1>";
                return false;
            }

        }

    }

    $IP2sping = array("pc1" => "192.168.1.121", "pc2" => "192.168.1.122", "pc3" => "192.168.1.123", "pc4" => "192.168.1.124");

    foreach ($IP2sping as $key => $value) {

        if (ping($value) == true) {
            echo $key . " alive<br>";
        } else {
            echo $key . " off<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I created a form to call the function with a submit button.  All of this works but my problems is trying to display the output outside the function.  For example currently all output is displayed like the following.

```
pc1 alive
pc2 alive
pc3 alive
pc4 alive
```

I want to know how the results of `pc1`, `pc2`, `pc3` and `pc4` can be displayed separately outside the function.

Comment: They *are* displayed outside the function. The code that prints the data lies outside the function. You are going to have to explain a little better exactly where/when you want the output displayed before we can help...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for answers, but I found a solution that works great for what I want to do using variables variables.

By changing $key to $$key pc1 pc2 pc3 and pc4 become variables and then I can use it anywhere I want.

```
$IP2sping = array("pc1" => "192.168.1.121",                   
                  "pc2" => "192.168.1.122",                   
                  "pc3" => "192.168.1.123",                   
                  "pc4" => "192.168.1.124");      


foreach ($IP2sping as $key => $value){     
     if (ping($value) == true) {         
         $key." alive<br>";    
      } else {         
         $key." off<br>";    } 
      }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's shown outside the function. Here is where you show the results.

```
if (ping($value) == true) {
        echo $key." alive<br>";
   } else {
        echo $key." off<br>";
   }
```

I would do something like that for what you want:

```
$available = null;
    foreach ($IP2sping as $key => $value){

   if (ping($value) == true) {
        echo $key." alive<br>";
   } else {
        echo $key." off<br>";
   }
}
```

Or

```
$available = null;
foreach ($IP2sping as $key => $value)
   $available[$key] = ping($value) ? true : false;
```

Then, you'll be able to use the `$available` array for whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
if (isset($_POST['playgroundcheck'])) {

  // Define the function
  function ping($PGIP) {
    require_once "Net/Ping.php";
    $ping = Net_Ping::factory();
    if (PEAR::isError($ping)) {
      return FALSE;
    } else {
      /* Number of packets to send */
      $ping->setArgs(array('count' => 2));
      $pgData = $ping->ping($PGIP);
      // print_r($pgData);
      return ($pgData->_received > 0);
    }
  }

  // Define array of items to ping
  $IP2sping = array("pc1" => array('ip' => "192.168.1.121"),
                    "pc2" => array('ip' => "192.168.1.122"),
                    "pc3" => array('ip' => "192.168.1.123"),
                    "pc4" => array('ip' => "192.168.1.124")
              );

  // Get the results of whether the machines are alive
  foreach ($IP2sping as $key => $value){
    $IP2sping[$key]['alive'] = ping($value);
  }


  /*
    Do a load more stuff
  */

  foreach ($IP2sping as $name => $data) {
    echo "$name ({$data['ip']}) is ".(($data['alive']) ? 'alive' : 'dead')."<br />\n";
  }

}
```